# Global Variables vs. Class Recursion and Overhead

Tags: php, oop, recursion

I'm building an app based on an existing MVC framework.

The native app bootstraps up by creating a registry object, then populates it with all the classes needed, which is great.

```
$registry = new \App\Registry;

$loader = new \App\Loader;
$registry->set('load', $loader);
```

But when a descendant class needs access to the registry or another instantiated object, they're passing in the registry object and setting it as variable in the object of the new class.

```
$theme = new \App\Theme($registry);
$registry->set('theme', $theme);
```

Then inside the theme class:

```
class Theme {

   private $registry;

   public function __construct($registry) {
      $this->registry = $registry;
   }
}
```

This is creating recursion on each instance and by the time the app gets to the front controller class, it's this huge bloated object with massive recursion that's completely unnecessary.

I know that using global variables is frowned upon, and I don't use them unless absolutely needed, but is it not much more efficient to simply call the registry object as a global only where it's needed so as to not have all this bloat?

My solution is to just call the registry as a global within the method in a given class where I need to access an object that's already been registered.

For instance in my example, let's say I need to access the loader object from within a method in Theme.

```
class Theme {

   public function __construct() {
      $this->setName();
   }

   public function setName() {
      global $registry;

      $loader = $registry->get('load');
      $loader->setName();
   }
}
```

This removes the need to set the registry as a variable inside theme, so that each object is only created once.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Are there security issues? Is there another technique that would produce the result I want without using a global reference?

Comment: You realise that injecting the registry into any class that needs it isn't creating multiple registry objects, just multiple references to the single registry object

Comment: But if classes don't need the registry object, then why inject it into them? Use a DIC, and ensure that only objects that actually need the registry store a pointer to it

Comment: Yes I do, but having my Controller object bloated with 6 or 7 references to say the Config object, which is quite large seems ridiculous.

Comment: That's kinda the point. They don't need the entire object, they normally only need access to a specific object within it, hence, use the global as opposed to passing it in. A DIC seems like overkill, are there any simple versions?

Comment: [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) is a pretty decent lightweight DIC, as is [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/); personally I like the use of annotations for such things

Comment: If there are no security issues then I see no reason to change it. It works beautifully using the global variable, much faster and more efficient.

Comment: If you see no reason to change it, then don't change it; you seem to have your mind fairly firmly set.... of course there is another option to avoid a global, and that's to use a singleton for your registry where you can simply call `getInstance()` when you need it

Comment: Don't get me wrong Mark I appreciate your help. Can you elaborate on your comment, perhaps in an answer? I just get frustrated with this "fan boy" crap ... globals are bad ... but no one ever elaborates on why they are so terrible.  I'm a practical guy, why do something the long way if the short way actually works better? If there's a good reason, I'm in, but if not ... if it's just coder arrogance, then that pisses me off :-)

Comment: Clarification on why globals are bad: they can be changed from anywhere in your code that can access them (which by definition is pretty much anywhere), so you can't guarantee that the content of any global var is consistent, nor easily identify where it might have been changed if it isn't what you expect it to be.... I'll write a longer answer tonight when I have more time